# How to use ADB to connect to smartwatch? Smartphone is connected with PC over WiFi while smartwatch is paired with the smartphone using Bluetooth?

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi

I know you can connect individually via `adb connect <IP>:<PORT>`. However, I would like the setup to be in the following manner:

- PC to smartphone => wifi
- Smartphone to paired smartwatch => Bluetooth

I don't want to connect to smartwatch directly using WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Here are the shell commands to connect to both smartphone and smartwatch.

```
adb connect <smartphone IP>:5555
adb -s <smartphone IP>:5555 forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
adb -s <smartphone IP>:5555 connect 127.0.0.1:4444
```